# Retrieving results quicker from a large table in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm working on an analytics project that requires me to pull some data from a very large table in Teradata. This is the query I'm using:

```
select TransactionNumber
from my_table
where TransactionDate between date '2017-01-01' and date '2017-12-31'
and ItemNumber in (99276);
```

Even though I'm filtering my_table for all of 2017, there are still almost 900 million rows that result from this query and the query takes a little over 30 seconds to run. Because of the nature of my project, I would like it to run in about 5 seconds or fewer, but given the size of the table, I'm not even sure if it's possible. Here's what shows up when I use 'explain' if it helps:

```
1) First, we lock DBTables.my_table in view
DB.my_table for access.
2) Next, we do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from 365 partitions of
DBTables.my_table in view DB.my_table with a
condition of ("(DBTables.my_table in view
DB.my_table.TransactionDate <= DATE '2017-12-31') AND
((DBTables.my_table in view
DB.my_table.TransactionDate >= DATE '2017-01-01') AND
(DBTables.my_table in view
DB.my_table.ItemNumber = 99276 ))") into Spool
1 (group_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs. The size of
Spool 1 is estimated with no confidence to be 617,535,066 rows (
14,203,306,518 bytes). The estimated time for this step is 2
minutes and 48 seconds.
3) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
in processing the request.
-> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
statement 1. The total estimated time is 2 minutes and 48 seconds.
```

Admittedly, I'm not all too familiar with optimizing queries and I only have read access to the database as I'm not a DBA.

Comment: Lots of questions...What kind of analysis are you doing with 900 million rows? What are you doing with the output of your query? Is your table partitioned by transaction_date? The explain plan looks fine, except for the "no confidence" bit. Work with your DBAs to get current statistics for that.

Comment: @Andrew My analysis: using a given item number, find the most frequently used/bought items alongside that item in a given transaction. So the query above is the really the preliminary step. I work in retail and so the database I use has hundreds of millions of rows due to daily transactions. I'm not sure if the table is partitioned by transaction_date, how can I check?

Comment: The plan shows it's partitioned by TransactionDate, no? (Have the DBA) check the DDL from `show table` to be sure. Retrieving 900M rows in 30 seconds is quite fast, I'd expect the server-client connection to be a bottleneck. Why is 30 seconds a problem? (I'd just store the result in a temp table once and work with it.)

Comment: You sell an item 900,000,000 times a year? Or is it the overall number of items for 2017? Assuming the estimated number of rows is totally wrong and you want to the the frequency processing within Teradata you (or your DBA) should fix the statistics problem first.

Comment: @dnoeth Yes, that means we sold about 900M of that item in 2017. Looks like I should work with the DBA then

Comment: @Nicolay 30 seconds isn't necessarily a problem for this item, but for other more popular items, I expect the number of rows to increase dramatically as well as the query execution time.

Comment: You got a pretty large system and this table is huge, too. So getting 900M rows in 30 seconds is probably ok (remember, there's other load on the system). If you got more propular items the execution time shouldn't increase that much, because it's probably mainly for scanning the base table. And estimating 600M vs. 900M is just a small difference, but *no confidence* still indicates missing statistics. What is the full query to analyse the frequencies?

Comment: @dnoeth I haven't developed the full query because I was trying to address this first. I expected that I would get much longer hangups with other items and so optimizing this became a priority.

Comment: Can you provide the definition from the view (SHOW VIEW) and the table (SHOW TABLE) along with the statistics that exist for the table (you should be able to query DBC.TableStatsV to get a list)? As others mentioned, 30 seconds is not a terrible service level for the suggested table size. Understanding the totality of your analysis and how much of it you can do in-database vs. extracting data into something like SAS will be helpful. Market basket analysis as you describe is not uncommon but remember this isn’t an OLTP workload.